# Next query is not executed until I materialize previous query by Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Sorry, if it is a really stupid question, but I cannot understand why `person.Cars` property is not populated. :

```
var persons = db.Persons.AsNoTracking()
    .Select(person => new PersonDto
    {
       ID = person.ID,
       Name = person.SP_Status.Name
    });

 //The following code where person.Cars is not populated until I write persons.ToList()
foreach (var person in persons)
{
    if (person.Name != "Adam")
    {
        person.Cars = (from ca in db.Cars                                       
            where ca.ID == person.ID
            select new CarDTO
            {
                ID = ca.ID,
                CarNumber = ca.DocNumber,                                           
            }).Distinct()
    }
    else
    {
        person.Cars = (from car in db.AnotherCars                                       
            where car.ID == person.ID
            select new CarDTO
            {
                ID = car.ID,
                CarNumber = car.DocNumber,                                           
            }).Distinct()

    }
}
```

If I materialize `persons` by `persons.ToList()` and then executing a populating `person.Cars`, then it works perfectly. But I have thousand objects in memory.

```
//this code works perfectly
persons.ToList();
foreach (var person in persons)
{
    if (person.Name != "Adam")
    {
        person.Cars = (from ca in db.Cars                                       
            where ca.ID == person.ID
            select new CarDTO
            {
                ID = ca.ID,
                CarNumber = ca.DocNumber,                                           
            }).Distinct()
    }
    else
    {
        person.Cars = (from car in db.AnotherCars                                       
            where car.ID == person.ID
            select new CarDTO
            {
                ID = car.ID,
                CarNumber = car.DocNumber,                                           
            }).Distinct()

    }
}
```

What I missed? Be very kind to explain and do not close this question, it is really important to me. Thanks in advance.

What I want to do is to fill `person.Cars` based on condition `person.Name != "Adam"` from tables `db.Cars` or `db.AnotherCars`.

Is it possible to rewrite this query without materializing (calling `.ToList()`) data in memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edited**. I have edited an answer because there was error in it.

After reading all comments, I decide that this problem could be solved by `UNION ALL` two left joins:

1. table `Persons`(with additional filter `person.Name != "Adam"`) left join table `Cars`
2. table `Persons`(with additional filter `person.Name == "Adam"`) left join table `AnotherCars`.

The result rows will be with columns:

1. PersonID
2. PersonName (I'm getting PersonName, if you need another, then change the selections)
3. CarID
4. CarNumber.

Here is the code for this query (I'm using another ORM. But it should work in EF, I guess):

```
// Getting persons.
var persons = db.Persons
                .Where(p => p.ID <= 10) // any of your filtering condition on persons
                .Select(p => new { p.ID, p.Name });

// Left join with 'Cars' table
var leftJoin1 = from p in persons.Where(p => p.Name != "Adam")
                join c in db.Cars on p.ID equals c.PersonID into j
                from c in j.Distinct().DefaultIfEmpty() // do you really need Distinc here?
                select new
                       {
                           PersonID = p.ID,
                           PersonName = p.Name,
                           CarID = c.ID,
                           CarNumber = c.DocNumber
                       };
// Left join with 'AnotherCars' table
var leftJoin2 = from p in persons.Where(p => p.Name == "Adam")
                join ac in db.AnotherCars on p.ID equals ac.PersonID into j
                from ac in j.Distinct().DefaultIfEmpty() // do you really need Distinc here?
                select new
                       {
                           PersonID = p.ID,
                           PersonName = p.Name,
                           CarID = ac.ID,
                           CarNumber = ac.DocNumber
                       };

// Resul query
var result = leftJoin1.Concat(leftJoin2)
                      .OrderBy(r => r.PersonID)
                      .ThenBy(r => r.CarID)
                      .ToList();
```

If it is sufficient for you to deal with with 4 properies (`PersonID, PersonName, CarID, CarNumber`), you need class for it and use it in left joins (instead of `select new {}` use `select new YourNewDTO {}`).

If you really need your DTO's then continue.

```
var personsWithCars = result.GroupBy(p => new { p.PersonID, p.PersonName })
                            .Select(g => new PersonDTO
                                         {
                                             ID = g.Key.PersonID,
                                             Name = g.Key.PersonName,
                                             Cars = result.Where(r => r.PersonID == g.Key.PersonID)
                                                          .Select(r => new CarDTO { ID = r.CarID, CarNumber = r.CarNumber })
                                                          .ToList()
                                         });
```

*imho, this is a necessary information:*

By *Ivan Stoev*:

> `persons` is a query. When you `foreach` it, it's executed, then you
>   do something with each element, but since you are not storing the
>   result, you basically do nothing. The next time you enumerate/tolist
>   etc. the persons, the query will execute again and give you brand new
>   objects. **However, if you remove `AsNoTracking`, you may get the same
>   objects**.
>
> `IQueryable<T>` is not a storage like `List<T>` etc. memory
>   collections. Even `IEnumerable<T>` isn't. e.g. `var q =
>   Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Select(i => new SomeObject { Id = i });`
>   **will create new objects anytime you enumerate it**.

Q: So it means `foreach` statement is never executed until I call `ToList()` method?

Answer by *NetMage*: No, it means that each person object only exists inside the `foreach` for one iteration. They are all lost at the end of the foreach.

Comment: Thank you very much for clarification to you all guys, Ivan Stoev, NetMage, Hemid Abbasov!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't run tolist() your query will not be executed until you actually request data because of delayed/deferred execution in LINQ queries. For the most part you just have an expression tree not actual objects. To switch to actual objects you have to call tolist().  In essence you are just adding to the query and not actually requesting the data.